# SSRS Export to Excel freeze header row not working

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel, ssrs-2008-r2

I have reports in SSRS 2008 R2 with freeze header row
but when export to excel the header not freeze.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that feature works with HTML rendering only. The freeze header row feature will not export to Excel.

The only way freezing a row works with exporting to Excel is when there is a page header as a part of the RDL (the header freezes at the top of each sheet). But, the results aren't what you probably want since the column headers usually are not in the header section of the report.